# where to deploy ibm db2 license file in apache karaf

Tags: java, db2, osgi, classpath, apache-karaf

I need to connect to db2 using a java.sql.DataSource , I installed the db2 driver, setup necessary beans in blueprint, everything is fine, until it gets to the point where the driver tries to make a connection. It fails with a very loud error message that the license file db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar needs to "be on the classpath"

Where should I put this file in karaf? I tried installing it as a "wrapped" bundle and doing Import-Package on the license package in the bundle that has the blueprint, but this doesn't seem to work. Should be deployed as a fragment to the bridge ?? should i repackage everything?

What is the "correct" way to deploy these "licenses" in karaf? Can't find anything about it in the manual.

Comment: Apache karaf is OSGi, maybe I should emphasize that more, so it works a little bit differently... My question is more about where to put the driver in karaf. I installed the driver db2jcc-2.10.52 it was used in a j2ee environment with 2 other license files db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar both same version as the driver

Comment: It seems that IBM added support for OSGi management of the jdbc driver in jdbc3.0 driver version 3.69.49 and jdbc4.0 driver version 4.19.49 and higher as "OSGi compliant bundling of driver jars".  If you have older versions then you need to upgrade them. Get the latest jdbc 4.0 driver from here https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads. Your version 2.10.52 is really antique, from Db2 v8.1fp14 .

Comment: Driver upgrade worked, thanks, wish the site was a bit easier to use, too many forms and licenses

Comment: P.s. For anyone that runs into this, don't even bother trying to repackage the driver and run it on later jvms, there's a dependency on a class in sun.io that was removed from later versions of java. So if you want to use the older driver (for whatever reason) you will need to hack together the missing classes and provide them for the driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded the driver, downloaded from here: http://ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads